# dynamic from name for SMS

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, mobileconnect

Is it possible to change the from name (sender ID) for MobileConnect with ampscript? Based on telecom regulations we need to send SMSes with different from names based on which country we're sending to.

Alternatively, is it possible to not send a SMS if the locale doesn't match? For instance, I would like to send the message *only* if the locale is not en-US or en-CA.

This would allow me to have all the subscribers in a single data extension and modify the ampscript to filter out locales

Answer (score 0):

**Regarding changing the "Sender ID" in MobileConnect:**
If you're referring to masking your short/long code, there is no way to mask the number legally, as it's been authorized by the carriers and aggregator to send messages exactly as it appears. That said, you can use Ampscript in your message to dynamically change the message content or any variable in it.

**Regarding locale mismatch:** 
Locale is effectively how marketing cloud "validates" the number to be sent to. I.e. the en-us locale will only send to messages formatted as 11 numbers (+1 555-555-5555) for example. It's strongly recommended that upon upload you choose to "normalize numbers" into your data extensions.

**Long and short here** - it sounds, based on your requirements, that you should segment your lists/DE's by locale, and target them independently for sends to maximize your ability to have meaningful reporting and to troubleshoot quickly.

Comment: Thanks Nate, I'm trying to use the locale field to filter out different locales. What I had in mind is to sort of segment using ampscript.

I'll edit the question so its clearer :)

Comment: Got it! You could definitely do that with an if/then loop in ampscript. I'd recommend checking out the Ampscript guide at http://ampscript.guide if you need coding examples! <br> As a best practice, however, I'd still recommend segmenting by locale so you have those DE's readily available for quick ad-hoc sends, rather than needing ampscript every time.